# Spring Boot Logback logging DEBUG messages

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, logback

I'm having trouble with Spring Boot spitting DEBUG level log items to terminal, when it should be in INFO level.

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>

</configuration>
```

**Dependencies in pom.xml** *(omitted everything that doesn't concern logging)*

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**The lines that keep showing up in terminal**

```
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [servletConfigInitParams]
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [servletContextInitParams]
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [systemProperties]
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [systemEnvironment]
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [random]
20:01:00.937 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]]
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [class path resource [sql.properties]]
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'serverServletmapping' in [localProperties]
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'serverServletmapping' in any property source. Returning [null]
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [random] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
20:01:00.938 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.MutablePropertySources - Adding [class path resource [sql.properties]] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
```

Comment: Do you have any logging configuration in application.properties or application.yml?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Wilkinson No, application.properties is completely empty and application.yml does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like logback did not find your `logback.xml` file. Please refer to [logback documentation on config file location](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation).

> Configuration files such as `logback.groovy`, `logback-test.xml` or `logback.xml` can be located directly under any folder declared in the class path. For example, if the class path reads `c:/java/jdk15/lib/rt.jar;c:/mylibs/` then the `logback.xml` file should be located directly under `c:/mylibs/`, that is as `c:/mylibs/logback.xml`.
>
> Placing it under a sub-folder of `c:/mylibs/`, say, `c:/mylibs/other/`, will not work.
>
> For web-applications, configuration files can be placed **directly under WEB-INF/classes/**.

Comment: It does, I can control the logging level of all other loggers and iI get a line `
00:17:50,675 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/.../src/main/resources/logback.xml]` in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

add this filter