# Spring debug logging level not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm trying to get spring to log at DEBUG level to troubleshoot an issue and no matter what I try it refuses to do it, it is permanently stuck at INFO level.

At first I had this as my logback.xml, and modifying packages other than org.springframework, e.g org.hibernate or springfox.documentation worked fine to modify the respective framework logging level:

```
<property resource="config/application.properties" /> 


<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>-App SE -- [%-5level|%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%logger] %msg%n%ex</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" />

<logger name="springfox.documentation" level="INFO" />

<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" />

<root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

After alot of playing around I eventually deleted the logback.xml and put this in application.properties after reading that spring could automatically pick up the value from there and set the log value accordingly:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

But alas no luck with that either.  Am I missing something, is there anything that could be overwriting the logging level back to INFO anywhere?

Here is my app startup, logs show logback being loaded, springframework level being set to debug, but nothing being logged from spring at DEBUG level:

```
[25/08/16 17:44:36:437 AEST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[25/08/16 17:44:36:454 AEST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.9/lafiles/en.html
[25/08/16 17:44:37:679 AEST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 1.402 seconds
[25/08/16 17:44:37:714 AEST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[25/08/16 17:44:38:352 AEST] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.security.ready.internal.SecurityReadyServiceImpl  I CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[25/08/16 17:44:38:848 AEST] 0000001e com.ibm.ws.security.token.ltpa.internal.LTPAKeyCreator       I CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.070 seconds.
[25/08/16 17:44:39:109 AEST] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[25/08/16 17:44:39:248 AEST] 00000023 com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 8090.
[25/08/16 17:44:39:864 AEST] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[25/08/16 17:44:39:866 AEST] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.cache.ServerCache                                 I DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[25/08/16 17:44:39:867 AEST] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[25/08/16 17:44:40:279 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application myapp.
[25/08/16 17:44:44:235 AEST] 0000002d org.jboss.weld.Version                                       I WELD-000900: SNAPSHOT
[25/08/16 17:45:08:729 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager.getAllDeclaredFields 249" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.08.0.log
[25/08/16 17:45:08:735 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorManager         W CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[25/08/16 17:45:08:742 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap.getAllDeclaredMethods 106" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.08.1.log
[25/08/16 17:45:08:742 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.MethodMap                      W CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$CompositeELResolverImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ScopeELResolver
[25/08/16 17:45:08:783 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,761 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:783 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,762 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:784 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/eclipse_workspace/myapp/myapp/target/classes/logback.xml]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:784 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,784 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[C:\eclipse_workspace\myapp\myapp\target\classes\logback.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
[25/08/16 17:45:08:784 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,784 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
[25/08/16 17:45:08:789 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,789 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:790 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,790 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:807 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,807 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
[25/08/16 17:45:08:857 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,857 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.web] to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:08:858 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,858 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.web] to true
[25/08/16 17:45:08:858 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,858 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework.web]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:858 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,858 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.boot] to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:08:859 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,859 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.boot] to true
[25/08/16 17:45:08:859 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,859 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework.boot]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:859 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,859 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [springfox.documentation] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:08:859 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,859 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:08:860 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [net.sf.ehcache] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:08:860 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [unknown.jul.logger] to OFF
[25/08/16 17:45:08:860 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,860 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:08:863 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,863 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
[25/08/16 17:45:08:863 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,863 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
[25/08/16 17:45:08:864 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:08,864 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@757d2cc6 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
[25/08/16 17:45:08:892 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [INFO |2016-08-25 17:45:08.891|org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension]Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
[25/08/16 17:45:09:159 AEST] 0000002d org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[25/08/16 17:45:09:169 AEST] 0000002d org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[25/08/16 17:45:09:169 AEST] 0000002d org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.internalProcessAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[25/08/16 17:45:10:283 AEST] 00000038 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0022W: Application myapp has not started in 30.004 seconds.
[25/08/16 17:45:10:403 AEST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, beanValidation-1.1, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, jdbc-4.1, jaxrs-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, el-3.0, json-1.0, cdi-1.2, distributedMap-1.0, webProfile-7.0, websocket-1.1, jpa-2.1].
[25/08/16 17:45:10:404 AEST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 32.723 seconds.
[25/08/16 17:45:10:404 AEST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[25/08/16 17:45:12:621 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: myapp.
[25/08/16 17:45:12:623 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module myapp has been bound to default_host.
[25/08/16 17:45:12:625 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:8090/myapp/
[25/08/16 17:45:12:648 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[25/08/16 17:45:12:652 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/myapp
[25/08/16 17:45:12:663 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[25/08/16 17:45:12:678 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.jsp                                               I JSPG8502I: The value of the JSP attribute jdkSourceLevel is "15".
[25/08/16 17:45:12:719 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheServiceImpl                            I DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[25/08/16 17:45:13:068 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]:.Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@6252c372]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:187 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON.SPRING_APPLICATION_JSONURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.0.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:199 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.spring.application.json.spring.application.jsonURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.1.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:802 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,802 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[C:\eclipse_workspace\myapp\myapp\target\classes\logback.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
[25/08/16 17:45:13:802 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,802 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
[25/08/16 17:45:13:804 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,804 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:804 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,804 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:805 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,805 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
[25/08/16 17:45:13:808 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,808 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.web] to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:13:809 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[org.springframework.web] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:810 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.web] to true
[25/08/16 17:45:13:810 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework.web]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:810 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework.boot] to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:13:810 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[org.springframework.boot] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:811 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springframework.boot] to true
[25/08/16 17:45:13:811 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework.boot]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:812 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [springfox.documentation] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:13:812 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[springfox.documentation] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:812 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.hibernate] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:13:812 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[org.hibernate] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:813 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,813 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [net.sf.ehcache] to INFO
[25/08/16 17:45:13:813 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,813 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[net.sf.ehcache] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:813 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,813 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [unknown.jul.logger] to OFF
[25/08/16 17:45:13:814 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,814 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@4be8ea3 - Propagating OFF level on Logger[unknown.jul.logger] onto the JUL framework
[25/08/16 17:45:13:814 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,814 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
[25/08/16 17:45:13:817 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,817 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
[25/08/16 17:45:13:817 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,817 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
[25/08/16 17:45:13:817 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O 17:45:13,817 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@4e1816e8 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
[25/08/16 17:45:13:832 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[25/08/16 17:45:13:832 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[25/08/16 17:45:13:832 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[25/08/16 17:45:13:832 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[25/08/16 17:45:13:832 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[25/08/16 17:45:13:833 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[25/08/16 17:45:13:834 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)
[25/08/16 17:45:13:856 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.spring.config.name.spring.config.nameURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.2.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:862 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.vcap.application.name.vcap.application.nameURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.3.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:868 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.spring.application.name.spring.application.nameURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.4.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:875 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.PORT.PORTURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.5.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:882 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.server.port.server.portURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.6.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:888 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.spring.application.index.spring.application.indexURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.7.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:895 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.vcap.application.instance_index.vcap.application.instance_indexURLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.13.8.log
[25/08/16 17:45:13:899 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [INFO |2016-08-25 17:45:13.899|com.mypkg.Application]The following profiles are active: lcl
[25/08/16 17:45:13:915 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [INFO |2016-08-25 17:45:13.915|org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext]Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1536b655: startup date [Thu Aug 25 17:45:13 AEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[25/08/16 17:45:13:915 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [INFO |2016-08-25 17:45:13.915|org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext]Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1536b655: startup date [Thu Aug 25 17:45:13 AEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[25/08/16 17:45:14:564 AEST] 0000002d com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.=.=URLContextFactory com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory 74" at ffdc_16.08.25_17.45.14.0.log
[25/08/16 17:45:15:972 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [DEBUG|2016-08-25 17:45:15.972|org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate]Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
[25/08/16 17:45:16:085 AEST] 0000002d SystemOut                                                    O -App SE -- [DEBUG|2016-08-25 17:45:16.084|org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate]Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
```

Comment: What version of Spring / Spring Boot are you relying on?

Comment: running on spring boot 1.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: What do your dependencies look like in your pom.xml? Do you have a dependency on the `spring-boot-starter-logging` library?

Comment: yes I do... I've taken screenshots of all my resolved dependencies: http://imgur.com/a/99Iy2

Comment: This one looks similar... their issue is it is stuck at DEBUG. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977512/spring-boot-logback-logging-debug-messages?rq=1

Comment: I've had a look, from what I can tell that issue could be related to their logback not being detected.  Mine is it seems, as I said I can update other packages like hibernate etc. and those will happily switch into debug, all except spring! I've attached the startup logs showing that logback is propogating spring logging as debug, but it's just not registering for some reason.  Appreciate your help.. this is driving me insane given its all for the purpose of debugging another issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me how the hell this worked but when I tried adding the properties to an external library in liberty profile and setting classloader delegation to parent last:

```
<webApplication id="myapp" location="myapp.war" name="myapp">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary>
            <folder dir="C:\ccviews\eclipse_workspace\classes\myapp" />
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
```

Then spring magically started spitting out logging at the desired level.  That was a good way to spend a day and a half!